# how to make vue1.0 session so i can use it another vue page too

Tags: javascript, session, laravel-5, vue.js

i am using Laravel 5.5 with vuejs1.0, in only laravel i can put some value in  session variable and can access it from another blade page. but now u am using vue1.0  as a frontend. so is there any possible way to make such kind of things in a minimal setup?

Comment: Integrate `vuex`, replicate the `messagebag` functionality of Laravel.

Comment: does vuex work in vue1.0 ?    and  i just saw vue-session. what is that? can u please explain?